How to fix calling a scipt from a controller that doesn't work, but running it in the text editor does?
I'm using UPBGE-0.36.1 on Windows 11. I installed a new python module (OpenCV) using the following commands in the UPBGE python console:
import site

import pip

pip.main(['install', 'opencv-python', '--target', site.USER_SITE])

I have a script in the text editor that uses openCV as shown in the below image:

When I push the "run" button in the text editor, the script runs perfectly. If I try to call the script from a Python controller (see down at the bottom of the image), I get the  python error in the UPBGE terminal shown below. Can anyone explain what is happening and how to fix this?
Error: Python.002(one), Python script error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\moore\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\moore\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 175, in bootstrap
    if __load_extra_py_code_for_module("cv2", submodule, DEBUG):
  File "C:\Users\moore\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 28, in __load_extra_py_code_for_module
    py_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "C:\UPBGE\upbge-0.36.1-windows-x86_64\3.6\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\moore\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\cv2\typing\__init__.py", line 159, in <module>
    Prim = _typing.Union[cv2.gapi.wip.draw.Text, cv2.gapi.wip.draw.Circle, cv2.gapi.wip.draw.Image, cv2.gapi.wip.draw.Line, cv2.gapi.wip.draw.Rect, cv2.gapi.wip.draw.Mosaic, cv2.gapi.wip.draw.Poly]
AttributeError: module 'cv2.gapi.wip.draw' has no attribute 'Text'


I should say the contents of the script past the two import statements are not relevant. It fails on the import part. It is like the console used a different python than the controller brick.

Usually you want to put external libraries into your config folder located approximately at C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\{version}\scripts. If you don't see a folder modules folder inside your scripts folder then make one and then either move the opencv2 folder in your Python site-packages folder to that modules folder. Or you can just install it fresh with pip and specify the install directory that way.

I placed the CV folder in C:\Users\moore\AppData\Roaming\UPBGE\Blender\3.6\config\modules and that solved the issue. I can't accept a comment as a solution. Would it be better for you to post that as an answer?

Though it only works once. Weird. If I hit the "P" button to start the game engine, the script runs. If I exit out of the game and hit "P" again, I get the same error. However this may be a different issue and out of scope for this particular question which you likely solved.

The complete solution to use OpenCV with upbge-0.36.1-windows-x86_64 is:

Open the python console in UPBGE and type the following commands:

    import sys

    import pip

    pip.main([ 'install', 'opencv-python==4.5.5.64', '--user'])

I initially tried to install opencv 4.10.0. This version is not compatible, and I had to use a older version. This will install cv2 at C:\Users\{name}\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages. Copy this cv2 folder to where the UPBGE folder in the following directory: C:\UPBGE\upbge-0.36.1-windows-x86_64\3.6\scripts\modules. I assume this is the same process for importing other modules into UPBGE.

Looks like my comment was at least half the answer anyways! Nice job

It was! Thank you very much. I really appreciate the help.
